# SQL Server - WHERE Date Range & GROUP BY MonthName

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping, where-clause

I have 2 same queries (to return "MonthName Year" and count) as below, but only the date range in the WHERE condition is different. Query 1 gets only the June month count, while Query 2 gets count from Apr to Jul, where the Jun month count (in Query 2) is not same as June month count from Query 1. Please advise.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, SubmissionDate) + ' ' + DateName(Year, SubmissionDate) AS MonthNumber, COUNT(1) AS InquiryCount 
, Cast(Datename(MONTH,SubmissionDate) + ' ' + Datename(YEAR,SubmissionDate) AS DATETIME) AS tmp
    FROM [dbo].[InvestigationDetails] (nolock)
    WHERE SubmissionDate>= '06/01/2016' 
    AND SubmissionDate <= '06/30/2016'
    GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, SubmissionDate) + ' ' + DateName(Year, SubmissionDate), DateName(Year, SubmissionDate)
    ORDER BY tmp ASC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, SubmissionDate) + ' ' + DateName(Year, SubmissionDate) AS MonthNumber, DateName(Year, SubmissionDate), COUNT(1) AS InquiryCount 
, Cast(Datename(MONTH,SubmissionDate) + ' ' + Datename(YEAR,SubmissionDate) AS DATETIME) AS tmp
    FROM [dbo].[InvestigationDetails] (nolock)
    WHERE SubmissionDate>= '04/01/2016' 
    AND SubmissionDate <= '07/31/2016'
    GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, SubmissionDate) + ' ' + DateName(Year, SubmissionDate), DateName(Year, SubmissionDate)
    ORDER BY tmp ASC
```

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: How is the June data in the first query different from the second?

Comment: Query 1 returns: June 2016 - 290 & Query 2 returns the count 307 for June 2016. Please advise.

Comment: Need the data to play with and see whats going on but to troubleshoot it try to change your where clause in the 1st query to:  where DATENAME(MONTH, SubmissionDate) = 'June'   .... see if that still gives you the same result as before.  Also is SubmissionDate a DateTime field or varchar ?

Comment: Jay did you figure this out

Answer (score 1):

`SubmissionDate` must be of type `DATETIME`and thus, you are missing all values for your last day, `06/30/2016`, since this equates to `06/30/2016 00:00:00`. This means any records that have `SubmissionDate` with a `time > 00:00:00 on 6/30/2016` will be excluded. For example, `6/30/2016 12:44:22` wouldn't be included in your results with your current logic.

Use one of these instead:

1. `AND SubmissionDate < '07/01/2016'`
2. `AND SubmissionDate <= '06/30/2016 23:59:59.999'`

The first method is preferred since you will get all records before 7/1/2016, which includes `6/30/2016 23:59:59.999`. Of course, you should be aware of how precise `DATETIME` can be in SQL Server. Run the code below to see what I mean.

```
 declare @dt datetime2 = getdate()
 select @dt         --more precise with datetime2
 select getdate()   --not as precise
```